# Hide all LI from a separate UL other than the first

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I want hide every LI from a UL other than the first, but the result is that it hides all except the very first LI of all UL's. (I want "show" the first LI of every UL).

How can i do that???

```
 <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
 </ul>

 <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
 </ul>
```

When i do this only identified the first item of all UL

```
    $('.smallYears ul li:not(:first)').hide();
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude the first `UL`, then you need to put the `:not()` on that.

```
$('.smallYears ul:not(:first) li').hide();
```

Or did you mean that you want to exclude the first `LI` of each `UL`. If so, do this:

```
$('.smallYears ul li:not(:first-child)').hide();
```

Or:

```
$('.smallYears ul li:nth-child(1)~li').hide();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

Completely untested, but something like the following might work.

```
$('.smallYears ul li:not(:first-child )').hide();
```

You're running into dramas as `:first` is basically an alias for `:eq(0)`, which is the first item in the jQuery collection.